# How can I manually add a line break in the title in a knitr RSweave file?

Tags: latex, knitr, sweave

Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{This is the document title}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I'd like something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{This is 
the document title}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

**How can I manually add a line break in the document title?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a line break:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{This is\\ 
the document title}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Surely it works, the problem should be another. If you send the code that doesn't work maybe someone in the community can explain why. Also works with bold in the title.

Comment: `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\\' on input line 311.` :(